# Create a comma-delimited list from a command's output

Tags: shell, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, sh, aws-cli

```
AUTOSCALING_NODES=$(aws elb describe-load-balancers --load-balancer-names $ELB_NAME --query LoadBalancerDescriptions[0].Instances --output text)
declare -a IP_ARRAY=($AUTOSCALING_NODES)
for i in ${IP_ARRAY[*]}; do ipaddress=$(aws ec2 describe-instances --instance-id $i --query Reservations[].Instances[].NetworkInterfaces[].PrivateIpAddresses[].PrivateIpAddress --output text); 
echo $ipaddress
```

These ips are output of above awscli. These should be placed in one variable with comma seperated as string.10.0.0.0
10.0.0.000

Comment: Can any one help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Include the sample output of `aws elb` and `aws ec2 describe-instances ...` in your question.  [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Google for "jq" - this will be too much of a pain in shell alone.

Comment: @stdunbar I am almost there. Now outputs is 10.0.0.0,
10.0.0.010.0.00.0,   Ip is duplicating

Comment: Updated the answer to eliminate dupes.  Please check.

Comment: Same output @codeforester

Comment: Are you sure your loop is running and producing output at each step?

Comment: [grepip] $ /bin/bash /tmp/hudson2255705336355327419.sh
10.0.0.0
10.0.0.010.0.0.0
[ssh-agent] Stopped.
Finished: SUCCESS  This is the outputs its getting ips but still duplicating. @codeforester

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting the `ipaddress` variable in the loop.  Instead, append it to an array and then format it after the loop:

```
declare -a ipaddress
for i in "${IP_ARRAY[@]}"; do
  ipaddress+=($(aws ec2 describe-instances --instance-id $i --query \
              Reservations[].Instances[].NetworkInterfaces[].PrivateIpAddresses[].PrivateIpAddress \
              --output text));
done

ipaddresses=$(printf '%s\n' "${ipaddresses[@]}" | sort -u | paste -sd, - | sed 's/,$//')
```

- `+=` inside loop appends the results to the array as new element
- `printf ... | sort -u | paste ...` converts deduped array into a comma delimited list

Comment: The above command is not working its not showing any output. Can you please help me bit. I am bit new to shell.

Comment: I got the output. But still a extra comma is comming at end. Can yu please let me know how to remove.  I gave echo -ne $ipaddreses to get them one after the other. Kind of 10.0.0.0,10.0.0.0,   . So dont need extra comma.